# Sql exclude some rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an MySQL table with channels (227) that contain this fields
`id, gener_id, channel_number, title ...`
I make an page that contain all channels with this sql query

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM channels ORDER BY channel_number");
```

But I want to exclude channels from 181 to 227 to **not** show in this table. How can I do this?

Here my whole code

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM channels ORDER BY channel_number");

 echo '<div class="table-responsive">';    
echo '<table class="table">';
    $i = 1; 
    while($row = $result->fetch()){

        if ($i==0){
            echo '<tr>';
        }

        $channel_name = $row['title'];
        $channel_number = $row['channel_number'];
        $channal_icon = $row['icon_url'];
        echo "<td>";
        echo $channel_number, '<br> ', $channel_name;
        echo '<br>'.'<img src="www.website.com'.$channal_icon.'" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: grey;" />'.'</br>';   
        echo "</td>";
        if ($i>3){
            $i=0;
            echo '</tr>';
        };  
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```

***UPDATE***
I've tryed with thist syntaxis

```
SELECT * FROM `channels` ORDER BY `channel_number`
EXCEPT
SELECT   `channel_number`
FROM     `channels`
WHERE    `channel_number` = '181'
```

But MySQL throw me an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXCEPT`

Comment: Um... (assuming channel_number is an integer data type)... `WHERE channel_number NOT BETWEEN 181 AND 227`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should do what you want. It is filtering out the range of channel_number that you don't want to display.

```
SELECT *
FROM channels 
WHERE channel_number not between 181 and 227 
ORDER BY channel_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE NOT BETWEEN`, which is inclusive to 181 and 227.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM channels 
WHERE channel_number NOT BETWEEN 181 AND 227
ORDER BY channel_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT * FROM `channels` WHERE `channel_number` NOT BETWEEN 181 AND 227 ORDER BY `channel_number`
```